# Shell Script (or Python) Curl Into Login Form With Forge Protection

Tags: python, shell, curl, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I got a form that has a hidden _csrf field in it. The value is a randomly generated number that changes each time you hit the page. I've done a lot of reading and testing and my attempts have failed with curl by itself. It seems people have got past similar issues with php, however I'm looking to do this from command line, so am looking for a shell script solution, or a solution in python, which I can call from the command line.

After logging into the form, it will create a cookie, which I'll need to reference for sequential POST commands afterwards.

**Failed Script example:**

```
#!/bin/bash
urloutput=$(curl -c ./curlcookie https://foo.com/login)
echo -e "$urloutput"
csrf=$(echo -c "$urloutput" | sed 's/.*csrf" value="//' | sed 's/"><p class=".*//')
echo -e "$csrf"
curl -b ./curlcookie -X POST -d username=user -d password=pw -d _csrf=$csrf https://foo.com/login/attempt
```

I've tried many variations of the script above. I've tried `/login` and `/login/attempt` (post location of the form). I've also tried `-F` instead of `-d` and also `--data "username=user&password=pw&_csrf=$csrf&submitBtn=Log%20in"` with and without the press. You can also see that I attempted the `-c` and `-b`, however those aren't really doing anything because the cookie isn't created until after the login of the form. So I've also tried removing the -c from the first command and replacing the -b with the -c, but to no success, still get the `Forbidden, invalid csrf token.` on the last command. So question is, how can I get the csrf value and submit it using the same session. I did not find anything special calling this out in the man pages. Thoughts on how I can achieve this?

**The form looks like:**

```
<form id="login-form" action="/login/attempt" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="etMCXWGw-qQ3wLGjHX9q_jB3YyxagvzLYpXs">

    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Network ID" required="">

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required="">

    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Log in">
</form>​​
```

I also noticed that if I edit the _csrf value in chrome inspector and then submit, then I get a similar response as what I get from the `curl` command that is failing.

**Curl Might Not Be Enough? Way to do it with Python?**

Its looking like the login attempts are getting a different csrf when trying to submit. This happens even if I look at the value in the cookie and try to use that. The 2nd command gets its own csrf. I'm opening my request to be something that can be run by shell, or through python, as I can call python stuff from shell. The key is, if with python, then I need a way to either get the cookie that was created so that I can use curl with it after to do POSTs, or a way to do sequential POST commands in the python script after login.

Comment: If the "random value" is a CSRF token, then the intention is that you'll post that value back, eg: `curl ...; sed ; curl -XPOST -d csrf=$csrf`. What's not working, exactly? Can you post example failures?

Comment: I'm pretty much doing what you show there but with extra logging and passing the user credentials too. The response I'm getting is `Forbidden, invalid csrf token.`

Comment: Can you also post the HTML form you GET on login?

Comment: @bishop updated the post to include what the form looks like too

Comment: I typically specify both `-b` and `-c` with the same value for all requests.  This way cookies will be read and written for each request, emulating a session.

Comment: Can you please update your post to show the correction for the underscore on csrf and using the input names instead of IDs? As both of those will definitely cause the failure you are seeing.

Comment: Does the csrf value you are capturing include a trailing newline?

Comment: Update to the commands were already done. No trailing newline.

Comment: Anding both the -b and -c to the commands did not affect anything.

Comment: FYI, using `echo -e` is bad form. `-e` is not even *allowed* (to do anything other than print `-e` on output) in POSIX-compliant `echo` (as in, a shell that implements it is not just extending the standard, but out-of-compliance with the standard's black-letter language), and even though bash disables it by default, that default isn't always the active configuration: When both the `posix` and `xpg_echo` flags are active, then even bash's `echo -e` prints `-e` on output. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section.